# Cardinality if a relationship depends on another one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, erd

I've a table which has a relationship with two other tables, the catch is that one of the two foreign keys will be null.

The thing is that a picture can either belong to a treatment or a client
and a treatment belongs to a client.
The problem is, if I only link to a client, i don't know which picture is tied to a treatment
and which not.

[image: Tables to join]

Solution? :

[image: Solution]

Thank you for any idea

Answer (score 1):

One way to adress this would be to create to separate mapping tables to represent the relationships between, on the one hand pictures and treatments, and on the other hand pictures and clients.

```
create table pictures_treatments(
    idPicture int,
    idTreatment int,
    primay key(idPicture),
    foreign key (idPicture) references t_pictures(idPicture),
    foreign key (idTreatment) references t_treatment(idTreatment)
);

create table pictures_clients(
    idClient int,
    idTreatment int,
    primay key(idPicture),
    foreign key (idPicture) references t_pictures(idPicture),
    foreign key (idClient) references t_client(idClient)
);
```

With this set-up in place, you can easily recover the picture associated with a treatment or a client with two left joins:

```
select t.*, p.picPath
from t_treatments t
left join pictures_treatments pt on pt.idTreatment = t.idTreatment
left join t_pictures p on p.idPicture = pt.idPicture;

select c.*, p.picPath
from t_clients t
left join pictures_clients pc on pc.idClient = c.idClient
left join t_pictures p on p.idPicture = pt.idPicture
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea but not exactly how to do it, why is there a primary key in the mapping table and on the pictures_clients, there is primary key(idPicture) but there is none?

Comment: Is my solution? part what you meant?